# How to use PHP CURL function to do the same request?

Tags: php, curl

Here is my `curl` commaad line .

```sh
curl -u 'username:password' -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d '<request><layout>1</layout><filtermode>category</filtermode><filtervalue>115399046</filtervalue><limit>1</limit><start></start><sortfield></sortfield><sortdir></sortdir></request>' https://example.com/contacts
```

I use `curl` command line. It works for me.  Now, I need do it in PHP.
The hard part is: The server accept `GET` request, but need a xml string in request body.   I have tried to change `GET` to `POST`, the server did NOT return the correct message.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init(); 
$credentials = "user:pass"; 
$data = 'xml string'; 
$page = "/contacts"; 
$headers = array( "GET ".$page." HTTP/1.0", "Content-type: application/xml", "Accept: application/json", "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials) ); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com/contacts'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

$ret = curl_exec($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us your code

Comment: The xml string does not display correctly.  anyway,  '1category1153990461' should be a xml string in request body.  When use command line, I use "-d" option.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
$credentials = "user:pass";
$data = 'xml string';
$page = "/contacts";
$headers = array(        
            "GET ".$page." HTTP/1.0", 
            "Content-type: application/xml",                  
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials)
);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/contacts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);  server got POST request,not GET

Comment: @KamanWu Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: `$headers` shouldn't include the `GET` line.

Comment: Sorry, this is my 1st question at stackoverflow.  Anyway, my code send POST request to server, but the server need a GET request.

Comment: @Barmar, I need send a GET request to server with request body.  When use command line, I use  -X GET  -d 'xml string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put the `GET` line in `$header`, that causes an invalid header to be sent. The PHP equivalent of `-X GET` is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
```